# Load Facebook adinterests list in a single API call

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api, geotargetting

Is there a way to load multiple adinterests by IDs in a single API call?

Here's situation:
We have multiple adinterests for ads targeting campaign. For example, we are targeting users that are interested in:

- music (ID=111)
- arts (ID=222)
- museums (ID=333)

We are listing all interests to a user, but **in the database we store only IDs**.

Currently we can only load single interest per request, e.g.:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/111?access_token=___
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/222?access_token=___
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/333?access_token=___
```

or

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/?access_token=___&type=adinterest&id=111
```

This works. However, I would like to load all interests in a single call to speed up page load, for example:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/?type=adinterest&id[0]=111&id[1]=222&id[2]=333&access_token=___
```

This, unfortunatelly, does not work.
So, is there any way to load ad interests list by list of supplied IDs?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Batch request framework to make a single HTTP request to multiple endpoints. See
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/batch-requests

Comment: Thank you for your answer, which pointed me to proper direction. Unfortunatelly, I cannot mark this answer as correct, because it does not exactly answer the question. It was a little tricky to figure out PHP script that finally worked so I posted it into separate answer.